# How can I speed up processing with DeleteCases?

Tags: performance-tuning, regions, data, filtering

I would like to get points that are only inside a region. Here are the region and unfiltered points:

```
reg = Polygon[{{-(π/3), -(π/Sqrt[3])}, {-((2 π)/3),
     0}, {-(π/3), π/Sqrt[3]}, {π/3, π/Sqrt[3]}, {(
     2 π)/3, 0}, {π/3, -(π/Sqrt[3])}, {π/
     3, -(π/Sqrt[3])}, {-(π/3), -(π/Sqrt[3])}}];
allPoints= Flatten[
   ParallelTable[{x, y}, {x, -2.5, 2.5, 0.01}, {y, -2.5, 2.5, 0.01}], 1];
```

Now, to get the points inside the `Polygon` I used

```
npont = DeleteCases[allPoints, ({x_, y_} /; {x, y} ∉ reg)];
```

but it takes too long. I waited for 5 minutes without output. How can I speed this up?

Comment: try `Select[RegionMember@reg]@allPoints`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As kglr says, you should use [`RegionMember`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMember). However, instead of mapping [`RegionMember`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMember) (which is basically what his [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select) code does), you should provide all the points at once to the [`RegionMemberFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMemberFunction). For example:

```
rmf = RegionMember[reg];

r1 = Select[rmf] @ allPoints; //AbsoluteTiming (* kglr *)
r2 = Pick[allPoints, rmf[allPoints]]; //AbsoluteTiming

r1 === r2
```

> {3.96721, Null}

> {0.083231, Null}

> True